# Cookie expiration not working on Symonfy 2

Tags: cookies, symfony

I am trying to set a cookie in a symfony2 project.
Everything is working fine, except that the cookie is deleted once the browser is closed. I tried to set an expiration time but it throws an error : `Expiry date cannot have a year greater then 9999`

How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
$time = time() * 3600 * 24 * 7;
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('lang', $lang, $time));
$response->send();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `$time` calculation should be

```
$time = time() + (3600 * 24 * 7);
```

Comment: This also helped me.